# Error handling in orange python script

Tags: orange, error-handling

Is there any workaround for error handling using python script in Orange?
I'm creating a python script module that only receive one column from in_data.
If there are more than one column exists in the in_data, I want my python script send an error message at the bottom right corner.
Thank you